# How to check if item in list is already in csv file?

Tags: pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I'd like to check each link in the list links to see if it is already in the CSV file, if it is not then I want to append it to the end of the file

```
for link in links:
    with open('shows.csv', 'w') as f:
        if link in 'shows.csv':
            links.remove(link) 
        else:
           with open('shows.csv', 'a') as f:
            df = pandas.DataFrame(data={"email": links})
            df.to_csv("./shows.csv", sep=',',index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this very basic example maybe you could try solve your example base on following:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create dataframe with list of values
d = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdefghijk')})

A
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
4   e
5   f
6   g
7   h
8   i
9   j
10  k
# create other list with some values common with list from dataframe above

list_of_values = list('bdefgiklp')
['b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'i', 'k', 'l', 'p']
# find those values that are in additional list and not in dataframe
remaining_items = list(set(list_of_values) - set(d.A.to_list()))

# in this case
['l', 'p']


# add those values to existing dataframe
d.append(pd.DataFrame({'A':remaining_items}), ignore_index=True)


A
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
4   e
5   f
6   g
7   h
8   i
9   j
10  k
11  l
12  p
```